# Angular.js - error with providerInjector

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with providers in angular, I get this error:

> Row 2696: Error: Unknown provider: a

Using unminified angular v 1.06, Row 2696:

```
providerInjector = createInternalInjector(providerCache, function() {
    throw Error("Unknown provider: " + path.join(' <- '));
}),
```

This is the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});

myApp.directive('buttonsRadio', function() {      
[...]
});


myApp.controller('MainController', function MainController ($scope) {
[...]
})
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Added error message:

```
Error: Unknown provider: aProvider <- a
createInjector/providerInjector<@/libs/angular.js:2696
getService@/libs/angular.js:2824
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@/libs/angular.js:2701
getService@/libs/angular.js:2824
invoke@/libs/angular.js:2842
instantiate@/libs/angular.js:2874
@/libs/angular.js:4759
applyDirectivesToNode/nodeLinkFn/<@/libs/angular.js:4338
forEach@/libs/angular.js:138
nodeLinkFn@/libs/angular.js:4323
compositeLinkFn@/libs/angular.js:3969
compositeLinkFn@/libs/angular.js:3972
nodeLinkFn@/libs/angular.js:4354
compositeLinkFn@/libs/angular.js:3969
publicLinkFn@/libs/angular.js:3874
bootstrap/resumeBootstrapInternal/</<@/libs/angular.js:963
Scope.prototype.$eval@/libs/angular.js:8011
Scope.prototype.$apply@/libs/angular.js:8091
bootstrap/resumeBootstrapInternal/<@/libs/angular.js:961
invoke@/libs/angular.js:2857
bootstrap/resumeBootstrapInternal@/libs/angular.js:960
bootstrap@/libs/angular.js:973
angularInit@/libs/angular.js:934
@/libs/angular.js:14756
f.Callbacks/n@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks/o.fireWith@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:2
.ready@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:2
B@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:2

/libs/angular.js
Line 5704
```

Answer (score 2):

Before running `uglify` or any other ofuscator/compression algorithm, you should run the grunt task `ng-annotate` which adds the dependencies as strings for you as an injectable array, this makes your code a lot cleaner as the injectable annotaion can be added automatically as a build step rather than having to manually code it.

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function MainController ($scope) {
[...]
})
```

Becomes:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function MainController ($scope) {
[...]
}])
```

Take a look at: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

**Update:**
[ng-min](https://github.com/btford/ngmin)   AngularJS Pre-minifier **deprecated** –> use ng-annotate

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using some kind of javascript obufuscator (Clousure, SquishIt, UglifyJS etc).

In this case you need to specify dependencies in such way:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], ['$interpolateProvider',function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
}]);

myApp.directive('buttonsRadio', function() {      
[...]
});


myApp.controller('MainController',['$scope', function MainController ($scope) {
[...]
}])
```

Note to specify dependenices for dependency injection - instead of passing function, you need to specify array with list of strings with names of objects to inject into parameters and the function itself.

Comment: I am actually using the source as is without obfuscation. I think I tried that solution (will try again), could it be something else?

Comment: Other option could be that you're passing somewhere function with parameter named 'a' where AngularJS expect function with injectable parameters (e.g. controller function even in directive definition object). Try to post part of your code into Plunker to reproduce error. In this case you can easier find a place + we could take a look and give you advice.

Comment: Seems I got rid of one error. Do I need to inject the $interpolateProvider into the directive and controller as well perhaps??

Comment: if you're not using that provider there, you can not pass. The good think in DI that you need to inject only what you're using. Only advice you is to split you definition of module into definition itself and configuring. like ```var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []); myApp.config(['$interpolateProvider',function (...)]);``` in this case it would be little bit more readable.

Comment: Thanks. Does not seem to be an "a" param. Added error message to the question, will provide Plunker if I can reproduce it there. Is there a better way to debug angular??